# Is there any running example code for Google login with authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic, google-openid

***PS:- please dont say use this devise, omniauth or any other plugin/gem you know.***

I am looking for some example code for google login using authlogic for ruby on rails 3.

Here is what i have tried/checked:-

- [authlogic-google-account-oauth](https://github.com/benaldred/authlogic-google-account-oauth) --- This is sample code for twitter, not google (One of the top rated google result. )
- http://www.manu-j.com/blog/add-google-oauth-ruby-on-rails-sites/214/ --> generating keys for google login?  There was nothing like this while implementing facebook / twitter or linkedin login. All I need is secret key and application id from the respective sites.
- Tons of links on stackoverflow, No-one is giving the solution just recommending other gems/ outdated blog posts like

  [Ruby on Rails: Best way to add Facebook login, Twitter login, OpenID login, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536438/ruby-on-rails-best-way-to-add-facebook-login-twitter-login-openid-login-etc)

  [Configuring authlogic-oauth with google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615372/configuring-authlogic-oauth-with-google) and many more.

Anybody knows any running example/ sample code for google login with authlogic in rail 3

**EDIT**

Have you noticed these warnings, this is from your code. The code you provided is running on my local machine:--

```
 Attempting discovery to verify endpoint
 Performing discovery on https://www.google.com/accounts /o8/id?id=AItOawlFBZciVpNUBSlYbz0wHzTgmJWu9PpCvyk
  WARNING: making https request to https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawlFBZciVpNUBSlYbz0wHzTgmJWu9PpCvyk without verifying server certificate; no CA path was specified.
  Using 'check_authentication' with https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud
WARNING: making https request to https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud without verifying server certificate; no CA path was specified.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inspired me to hack away at this.

This blog basically worked for me http://blog.sethladd.com/2010/09/ruby-rails-openid-and-google.html

My code is extra ugly though, because it wasn't the first one I tried.
Other resources:

[Ruby open_id_authentication with Google OpenID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492043/ruby-open-id-authentication-with-google-openid)

http://toddsedano.blogspot.com/search?updated-max=2010-05-29T11%3A59%3A00-07%3A00&max-results=7

http://railscasts.com/episodes/170-openid-with-authlogic

Anywho, the rough code that is working for me is here: 
 https://github.com/softwaregravy/google_authlogic
and [here is the running code](http://www.google-authlogic.com)

It's still very much a prototype.  Hope it helps.

Comment: A beer jug for you.. Thanks a lot.. I think once I done with my current project. I should fork your repo to add facebook, and twitter login too. Will do that for sure.. Thanks a lot bro..

Comment: Yes.  Different ballgame.  You'd need to have your host set up with Certs (i.e. Verisign).  I'm guessing that's why with facebook apps, you always have to switch back to http:// and not https://

Comment: Ok. and what about that Rack::OpenID issue. Do u have any idea. Like same stuff is working in your code. I checked your environment.rb file etc. There is not as such any declaration. Why I am getting that error.

Comment: Not all of the magic columns seem to be supported right now either.  I'm thinking I need to actually create an actual session somehow for the user, but without needing a password.  I've also disabled checking of passwords and stuff, but you'd actually want that if you intend to allow regular log ins next to openid logins

Comment: Hey. It worked.. Only issue is that warnings. I will check those things and will be back.. :-)

Comment: warnings discussed in the context of devise https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/185

Comment: One of my links discussed how to fix the error: http://toddsedano.blogspot.com/2010/05/integrating-openid-google-apps-and-ruby.html